# Substituting header files without modifying source

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My use case here is a bit odd: I've got a bunch of source files from upstream that have an `#include <assert.h>` in them. It's *possible* in some cases, though not certain, that `assert.h` is present in the system include path and everything goes well. However, in some other cases there is no `assert.h`.

To simplify things, I want to replace all the references in the source to `<assert.h>` with `"myassert.h"` (note the quotes in the latter). Of course the easiest solution is just `sed -i ...`, but preferably I'd leave the upstream source files unmodified so it would be easier to integrate new changes.

Passing a -D flag to the compiler won't help with the angle brackets to quotes substitution, and searching around gives no hits. Any ideas?

Comment: What VCS are you using?

Comment: If you don't wanna change sources you.may wanna try changing include paths so that desired assert.h is found first

Comment: @EliSadoff Git, but how is that relevant?

Comment: @theunamedguy You were talking about not changing upstream source files. I was trying to think of if there was potential a version control specific way to do this.

Comment: `assert.h` is one of the standard headers, and it has been since C was first standardized (C89).  If you truly need to deal with implementations that do not provide `assert.h`, then you should also be concerned about other ways in which those implementations fail to conform.  Are you sure this is a *bona fide* issue for you, not just a speculative one?

Comment: Note also that the double-quote form of the `#include` directive is not guaranteed to differ from the angle-bracket form in any way other than syntax.  Inasmuch as you are concerned with implementations that don't even conform to the standard in the first place, it seems unwise to rely on any particular semantics for the quoted `#include` beyond those of the other form of `#include`. Implementations *do* vary.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Looks like I was incorrect when I said that there was no `assert.h`. However, it fails to link in some cases due to the error handler for failed assertions not being defined, so in those cases assert() is useless.

Comment: I should also say that the compiler used in this case is an older, but still mostly standards-compliant GCC.

Comment: @theunamedguy, `assert.h` being present but the `assert()` macro expanding to non-functional code is not any better from a conformance perspective than `assert.h` being absent altogether.  It may be, however, that on some systems you need to explicitly link an additional library to support assertions.  Alternatively, you could consider simply suppressing assertions by defining `NDEBUG`.